# Read text from file (c#) of unknown number of lines and add lines to predefined labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a windows form application. I need to read text from a particular file, i am not sure of the number of lines that will be in this text file at a given time but i need to retrieve each line and display them on a form page. i have tried to store the string in an array but i get an error "Make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size".

Also note that i have created some labels on certain positions for each lines, (i made about ten labels). This is the portion of the code giving me problem:

```
            string[] edfTaskList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(edfTaskfile);
            oldtask1.Text = edfTaskList[0];
            oldtask2.Text = edfTaskList[1];
            oldtask3.Text = edfTaskList[2];
            oldtask4.Text = edfTaskList[3];
            oldtask5.Text = edfTaskList[4];
            oldtask6.Text = edfTaskList[5];
            oldtask7.Text = edfTaskList[6];
            oldtask8.Text = edfTaskList[7];
            oldtask9.Text = edfTaskList[8];
            oldtask10.Text = edfTaskList[9];

            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask1);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask2);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask3);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask4);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask5);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask6);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask7);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask8);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask9);
            oldTaskPanel.Controls.Add(oldtask10);
```

Comment: I think that if you want to have a static number of controls in your form you should know beforehand what is the upperbound to the number of lines you can find in the file.

Comment: If you don't know the number of lines in the file how can you add the labels for this lines? Why you don't show the text in multiline text box?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
private int lastLablePos;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lastLablePos = panel1.Location.Y;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test.txt");
        Label[] labels = new Label[lines.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            labels[i] = new Label();
            labels[i].Text = lines[i];
        }

        foreach (Label lable in labels)
        {
            lable.Location = new Point(0, lastLablePos);
            lable.AutoSize = true;
            panel1.Controls.Add(lable);
            lastLablePos += 30;
        }
    }
```

and finally add those labels to form with coordinates etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but am getting an error that says: the type or namespace Labels could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference, the second error says label does not exist in the current context.

Comment: It's a typo, I edited my answer. you can try now it should work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the array totally got 10 or more entries? I guess that this is the problem, you are addressing more values than you actually have.

Either loop through your entries (by using a foreach loop) and create your labels dynamically or use other control elements as Saverio Terracciano mentioned.

Comment: You are right,am not sure what number of lines will be available in the text file because the text file is being updated by some other codes. i dont mind if there is a way to have an upper bound but i dont know how to go about it.

Comment: How about a foreach loop? Loop through all strings in the array, this way you don't need to check if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: He still has just 10 controls to show the lines. Even if he were to iterate through it with a foreach loop, he wouldn't be able to show all the content.

Comment: Of course, he will need to create them dynamically or use another set of controls as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, am going to implement the for each loop and then create the labels dynamically. Am trying that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use File.ReadLines instead of File.ReadAllLines and use a DataGrid to display your data, see 
[File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That wouldn't solve his problem if he is reading > 11 lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different approaches you could use to solve your problem, which is rather broad, assuming you have no way to have an upperbound on the number of lines you could:

- Build and add dynamically the controls you need to show the lines you read in your file
- Use a different kind of control like a ListBox or a DataGrid